# Entity Frameworks auto code generation and validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, visual-studio

I'm trying to learn Entity Framework. I have a database but it's not complete yet so i will add fields to my database and my model in future. I can do that easily and Entity Framework updating the class code accordingly. The problem is, for example i add this line to the code:

```
[Required()]
```

So it becomes like this:

```
[Required()]
public string BranchName { get; set; }
```

After adding a new field to database and my model, this code gets generated again and parts i include disappears. This makes sense and there is a huge warning above the code saying **Auto Generated** but i need to deal with it somehow. I want to use validation codes but i want to add new fields to the database too (obviously).

I can manually add my new fields to classes but how can i disable auto code generation? Also i don't want to do this if there is an other way, because i will change my models very frequently and it will be hard if there are so many new fields.

Hope i'm clear enough, thanks.

Comment: What's your problem exactly?!

Comment: @SirwanAfifi Well, i create a model based on my database, i add some validation code to classes, after i change my model, Entity Framework regenerates the classes so my code disappears. I want to fix that.

Comment: You can use Entity Framework Code First Engineering.

Comment: @Oluwafemi I want to use the designer too, is there a way to disable auto code generation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074468/how-do-i-stop-entity-framework-from-generating-both-objectcontext-and-dbcontext this might help.

Comment: Could you show one of the generated classes?

Comment: I can't change "Code Generation Strategy", it's disabled. I'm using VS 2015 and it seems you can't change it. So, how people add validation code to auto generated class?

Comment: you should use code first instead of database first, you seem to mix those two currently. for this, look at the database initializers www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I read many things about code first but it seems you can't use the entity designer with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any ways of adding data annotations to auto-generated classes.

The override behavior is the problem with the designer approach (and not only I believe but can't recall any other issue now). Therefore EF7 will only support code first as it's a more clean and safe approach since your classes don't get overwritten.

**So you will have to use code first for your needs.**

If you still want to use the designer you could try as an alternative a tool that can show you a live view of the database (SQL Server Express I think it's called) that gives you the same view)

Comment: Time to learn code first then. I'm only starting so it's right time to learn. Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: Yes, i'm using the code but it seems i need to add some more code like [Key] etc...